# Changing JSON Object Format

Tags: javascript, json, format

i got a JSOn object with over 200 entrys. Actually it looks like

```
params =    {
      key_a_1 : "value_a_1"
      key b_1 : "value_b_1"
      key_c_1 : "value_c_1"
      key d_1 : "value_d_1"
      key_a_2 : "value_a_2"
      key b_2 : "value_b_2"
      key_c_2 : "value_c_2"
      key d_2 : "value_d_2"
    }
```

and I need to convert it to

```
 params =   {
        1
            {
              key_a : "value_a_1"
              key b : "value_b_1"
              key_c : "value_c_1"
              key d : "value_d_1"
            }
        2
            {
          "key_a : value_a_2"
          "key b : value_b_2"
          "key_c : value_c_2"
          "key d : value_d_2"
        }
}
```

key can be named anything else but the number is always the id.

any idea whats the best way? thanks!

Basically the problem is, that I need the ID which is at the end of the key as an own array inside the JSON Object and my Javascript skills aren't great enough.

Comment: Pretty straightforward: Create a new object, iterate over all values and add them to new objects based on the last part of the value (those new objects are added to the object in step one). If you have a specific question, we are happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the properties and fill them into another object:

```
var newObject = {};
Object.keys(oldObject).forEach(function (key) {
     var name = /(key_\w+)_\d+/.exec(key)[1],
         index = /key_\w+_(\d+)/.exec(key)[1];
     if (!newObject[index]) {
         newObject[index] = {};
     }
     newObject[index][name] = oldObject[key];
});

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: This worked for me `function ExtractId(str){
 var params = str.split('_');
 return params[params.length - 1];
}
 
var newObject = {};
Object.keys(oldObject).forEach(function (key) {
     var name = /(key_\w+)_\d+/.exec(key)[1],
         index = ExtractId(key);
     if (!newObject[index]) {
         newObject[index] = {};
     }
     newObject[index][name] = oldObject[key];
});`